# Java netty tcp server with postgres. Query hangs indefinitely

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, tcp, netty

I write Spring Boot application with tcp server on Netty. Service get messages and check rows in postgres database. The problem is that at the moment of checking the records in the database, the service hangs and stops processing other messages from the tcp channel.

Configuration:

```
 @Bean
public void start() throws InterruptedException {
    log.info("Starting server at: {} ", tcpPort);
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(workerGroup, bossGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(simpleTCPChannelInitializer)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(tcpPort).sync();
        if(f.isSuccess())
            log.info("Server started successfully");
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();

}
```

Channel initialization:

```
 private final EventExecutorGroup sqlExecutorGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(16);

protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder());
    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());
    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(sqlExecutorGroup, simpleTCPChannelHandler);
}
```

and method for database:

```
    @Override
public void processMessage(String atmRequest) {
        log.info("Receive tcp atmRequest: {}", atmRequest);
        checkDeviceInDatabase(deviceUid);
        log.info("Receive power up command");
}

private void checkDeviceInDatabase(String deviceUid) {
    statusConnectRepository.findById(deviceUid).orElseThrow(()
            -> new DeviceNotFoundException("DeviceUid: " + deviceUid + " was not found in database"));
}
```

In checkDeviceInDatabase(deviceUid) method query hangs forever.
Has anyone met such a problem?